# 'New replies available' highlighted after starting at 'recent activity' page

Tags: feature-request

I've taken to jumping straight to my 'new replies' page to see what has happened while I'm away.  However, when I do this and there is a new reply, then when I open one of those questions for which there is a reply, that question has the 'there is a new reply' envelope highlighted, even though I've just come from the 'new replies' page.

Can this be fixed?

On a scale of 1-10 for irritation factor, it is no more than a 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an optimization designed to minimize the load on the StackOverflow database.  The envelope highlighting does not occur in real-time; rather, it most likely happens as a result of one of those polling things that periodically updates a separate table containing the envelope statuses.

In other words, the website occasionally takes a hit for updating everyone's envelopes all at once, rather than dying a quiet death updating each envelope individually everytime someone hits F5.  In the former case, only one record in one table has to be checked; in the latter case, all of your questions and answers have to be checked for activity.